# How to change order of charateristics ID discovered while scanning peripheral using core bleutooth ios

Tags: ios, swift, core-bluetooth

I am using core bluetooth framework in ios and scanning and discovering 2 charateristics ID but i want their order to be different then what I am getting so is it possible to change their order or anything programmatically?

**code**

```
   if (service.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("F4F2-BC76-3206341A")))
    {
        println(service.characteristics.count)
        for aChar:CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]

        {
            println(aChar)
            println(aChar.UUID)

            /* Write data*/
            if aChar.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("D0F0AECD-6405-0B040047"))
            {
                var str:NSString = "heyaa..!!"
                data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
                peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: aChar, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
                println("Write performed")
            }

            /* read data  */
            if aChar.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("C8853E-A248-C6F0B1"))
            {
                peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(aChar)
                println("Read performed")
            }
        }
    }
```

In this characteristics ID for reading data is getting called first but i want to call write data characteristics ID first so is there any way to resolve. Please help me out. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The characteristics will be discovered in an arbitrary and undefined order, but that shouldn't matter.

You should store a reference to the discovered characteristics so that you can write to them as required.

You app should go through distinct phases

1. Scan for and discover peripherals advertising specific service(s)
2. Connect to the target peripheral
3. Discover the characteristics of the service
4. Read/Write data as required - repeat this step as required
5. Disconnect

For example:

```
    var writeCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic?
    var readCharacteristic : CBCharacteristic?

    optional func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral!, didDiscoverCharacteristicsForService service: CBService!,error error: NSError!) {    

      if (service.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("F4F2-BC76-3206341A"))) 
      {

        println(service.characteristics.count)
        for aChar:CBCharacteristic in service.characteristics as [CBCharacteristic]

        {
            println(aChar)
            println(aChar.UUID)

            /* Write data*/
            if aChar.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("D0F0AECD-6405-0B040047"))
            {
                self.writeCharacteristic=aChar
            }
            else if aChar.UUID.isEqual(CBUUID.UUIDWithString("C8853E-A248-C6F0B1"))
            {
                self.readCharacteristic=aChar

            }
        }
      }
      if (self.writeCharacteristic != nil && self.readCharacteristic != nil) {
            var str:NSString = "heyaa..!!"
            data = str.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
            peripheral.writeValue(data, forCharacteristic: self.writeCharacteristic!, type: CBCharacteristicWriteType.WithResponse)
            println("Write performed")
      }
    }

    optional func peripheral(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral!,didWriteValueForCharacteristic characteristic: CBCharacteristic!,error error: NSError!) {
       peripheral.readValueForCharacteristic(self.readCharacteristic!)
       println("Read performed")
    }
```

Comment: My doubt is does hardware's characteristics ID get scanned in alphabetical order ? like first "C882" and then "D889". It is not finding in arbitary manner it has fixed order.

Comment: I want ID "D889" get discovered first then other ID "C882" get discovered for that what should I do? Please help me.

Comment: You can't control the order in which characteristics are discovered and nor should it matter.  You need to structure your code so that the order doesn't matter.

Comment: if hardware team says that it is ID "C882" for read operation but read operation will not give me output unless i perform write operation so first i have to perform write operation to get value read. It can be mistake from for ID description? Is any where written that we can't control order as I have to prove it. thanks

Comment: The order doesn't matter.  I have updated my answer to show one approach to processing the characteristics.

Comment: First I am writing message which calls did write method with response then for reading read value method is called which calls update method. So can i get the message written during write method in update method during reading it??

Comment: I can't really parse that sentence. If you need the message that you wrote in another method, just store it in a property

Comment: I want to make communication kind of. Like If i am writing message "hi" in write method which will call did write with response then by calling read method am i able to read the message "hi" written in write method?

Comment: Read it from the peripheral?  It depends on whether the device exposes that information

Comment: yes read it from peripheral by writing this code **var str:NSString = NSString(data: characteristic.value, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding)** Is it possible to get that same value if hardware is prepared to provide echo back functionality.